# After I finish doing texture paint when I go to viewport my object is purple anyone knows how to fix it?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, texture-painting

When I finish my texture in texture paint on my object and go to viewport shading the whole donut goes purple and I don't know how to fix it.
But on the other settings I can see my texture perfectly it's only on viewport mode.

Also I have noticed that in shading once I don't connect the base color on prinicipled BSDF node to the color on image texture node the purple color disappears but then there is no texture and I need it to finish my render so if anyone has the answer that would be great thank you :)

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: Can you include some screen shots so we can see what your nodes and settings look  like? To see the problem is half the battle here.

Comment: Yes one second I'm adding it now

Comment: welcome to the Blender SE! It appears to be that materials turn purple when there is a problem with the image texture (file not found, no texture imported etc.). Have you tried to re-link the nodes or to import the texture again?

Comment: Thank you! :) I did try to re-link the nodes several times I even deleted it and made it again but it didn't help, as for the import I did not I'm not sure how to do it if you can explain that would be awesome! :)

Comment: Did you save your blend file and still had the texture afterwards, i always include everything in saves.